# Motivation behind definition of density of state

Tags: electronic-band-theory, density-of-states

The definition of density of state *per unit volume* stated in Girvin and Yang's *Modern Condensed Matter Physics* is $$\rho(E)=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3} \delta(E-E')$$

I would like to gain more intuition on this definition. Why is it defined this way?

On a related note: naively, I would think that $\int dE \space\rho(E)$ (I am not sure what the integration bound should be) will give me the number of particles *per unit volume*, but it doesn't seem to be the case. For example, if I treat the free particle case $\left(E'=\frac{\hbar ^2k'^2}{2m}\right)$, I have $$\int dE \space\rho(E) =\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}\int dE \space \delta(E-E')=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}E'=\int \frac{d^3k'}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\hbar ^2k'^2}{2m}=\frac{\hbar^2}{(2\pi)^32m}\int (4\pi)k'^4 dk'=\frac{\hbar^2k^5}{5(2\pi)^2m}$$

which doesn't even seem dimensionally correct.

Comment: note that $\int \! dE \delta(E-E') = 1$ and not $E '$ as you wrote (assuming that the integral is over all energies).

Comment: Are you asking why the density of states (#states at energy $E$) has that mathematical expression? Why we consider such quantity? It would be helpful if you could ask about something more specific that you don't understand (in Girvin and Yang's explanation or other sources).

Regarding the "related note": it is not dimensionally correct because of the error pointed out by @yu-v.

Comment: @yu-v thanks for catching that mistake. Then the dimension makes sense.

Comment: @fqq Yes to your 1st question, it would be great if you could explain that.

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_of_states#Definition) clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll generally be interested in the density of states of a system with a non-trivial dispersion, like the bands in a crystal $\epsilon_{n}(\vec k)$. For physical intuition, I think it helps to write the density of states per unit volume a little more suggestively (G&Y eq. 7.94):
$$\rho_n(E)=\int_{BZ}\frac{d^3\vec {k'}}{(2\pi)^3}\delta\left(E-\epsilon_n(\vec {k'})\right)$$
This equation answers the question, "in the $n^{th}$ band, how many states are there per unit volume at energy $E$?" The integral probes all momenta in BZ, and when it comes across a $\vec k$ mapped to $E$ by $\epsilon_n(\vec k)$, the delta function "clicks," thereby counting the contribution of that state to the total number of states at energy $E$. In this way, you count the *degeneracy* at energy $E$.

Since $\rho_n(E)$ counts the states in band $n$ at a given energy $E$, integrating over $E$ and summing over $n$ gives the *total* number of states per unit volume.

To flesh out your example a little more, consider a free Fermi gas at $T=0$ with the dispersion you cite. We have:
$$\int dE' g_s\rho(E')f(E')=2\int dE'\int_{BZ}\frac{d^3\vec {k'}}{(2\pi)^3}\delta\left(E'-\frac{\hbar ^2k'^2}{2m}\right)\Theta(E_F-E')$$
The result of the $E'$ integral is:
$$=2\int_{BZ}\frac{d^3\vec {k'}}{(2\pi)^3}\Theta\left(E_F-\frac{\hbar ^2k'^2}{2m}\right)=2\int_{BZ}\frac{d^3\vec {k'}}{(2\pi)^3}\Theta\left(\frac{2 m E_F}{\hbar^2}-k'^2\right)$$
Assuming isotropy in $\vec k$ and defining $k_\text{max}\equiv\sqrt{\frac{2 m E_F}{\hbar^2}}$:
$$=2\int_0^{k_\text{max}}\frac{d{k'}}{(2\pi)^3} 4\pi k'^2 =\frac{k_\text{max}^3}{3 \pi^2}$$
Substituting the canonical result $E_F=\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{3\pi^2N}{V}\right)^{2/3}$, we finally arrive at $\boxed{\frac{N}{V}}$, as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Chris! It clarifies almost all my confusion, with one detail remaining: where does this factor of $2$, at the step, $2\int_0^{k_\text{max}}\frac{d{k'}}{(2\pi)^3} 4\pi k'^2$,  come from?

Comment: And I especially like your analogy for the delta function in picking up energy degeneracy, it just *clicks* with me ;)

Comment: Glad it was useful! Factor of 2 is from restricting the bounds of the integral to only positive k :)

Comment: I am confused about that, because it seems redundant: the factor of $4\pi$ arises from integrating over the solid angle, which already covers the sphere, so the radial component should be only in the range $[0,k_{max}]$ without any extra symmetry factor, right?

Comment: Ah you’re so right, the factor of 2 needs to be in the final answer, but it should’ve been introduced at the start to account for spin degeneracy. I’ll correct the answer

Comment: Ah ok it is for spin degeneracy. That makes sense, thanks!